# Giving two inline-block elements a 50% width using the box-sizing property

Tags: html, css, border-box

I have a parent div that has a padding of 20px. Inside this div there are two span tags. I'd like their width to be 50% of the parent div and fit on the same line. `box-sizing: border-box` didn't seem to fix the issue.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}

div span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

It looks like `box-sizing` wasn't necessary for this use-case and CBroe's answer solves the problem accordingly.

Comment: span { `display:block; float:left` }

Comment: There's no way to do this without floats?

Comment: You can try to position them absolute if you do not want to use floats, but float would be a better solution.

Comment: The white space between the elements is your problem … http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @CarlEdwards - are floats not supported any more? What's wrong with using floats?

Comment: You should use [`flexbox`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for this. `display:flex` on parent and `width:50%` on your childs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The white space between the elements is your problem.

inline-block elements are laid out pretty much like normal text, and so the white space between one element’s closing and the next element’s opening tag gets condensed to one single space character according to general HTML rules – and that makes 50% + one space character + 50% end up being a little more than 100%, and so the second element breaks into a new “line”

There are several ways to try and fight this – from eliminating the white space between the element’s tags, setting font-size to 0 for everything “outside” those elements … Some of them are discussed in more detail here: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

There's a 100 ways to do this (maybe exaggeration, but I can think of at least 4).

Easiest way is to make them `block` elements (borders added for clarity):

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
span { display: block; width: 50%; float: left; padding: 12px; text-transform: uppercase; border: 4px solid #000; background: #f00;}
div { border: 2px solid #0f0; overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>first span</span>
  <span>second span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you truly can not use float, http://fiddle.jshell.net/z3xj0gwx/1/ this would work as well. But I would recommend using this solution with float: left;